# How to add item in cart and display it without refresh?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I have a button which adds item to the cart. How do I fix my code to display item on `html` page if quantity is less than one? Now my code adds item on the server and send `Json Object` to the client, but it doesn't show on the page. Seems like I need to display item with `AJAX and JQUERY`? I am quite new to Jquery and Ajax, so I'd be grateful to find a solution here!

base.html

```
{% if cart|length == 0 %}
    <div class="card-basket__body prod-tab" id="test">
        <div class="prod-tab__body">
            <p style="margin-top:20px;">В настоящий момент в корзине нет товаров...</p>
        </div>
    </div>                  
{% else %}

{% for item in cart %}  
    <div class="card-basket__head">
        <div class="card-basket__point" id="productAmount_{{item.product.id}}">{{ item.quantity }} шт.</div>
            <div class="card-basket__remove" data-type="popup-remov">Delete</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-basket__body prod-tab">
           <div class="prod-tab__body">
               <div class="prod-tab__name">
                   <picture>
                       <source srcset={% static item.product.image.first %} type="image/webp" />
                       <img src={% static item.product.image.first %} alt="" class="prod-tab__img" />
                   </picture>
               <div class="prod-tab__about">
                   <h3>{{ item.product.name }}</h3>
                   <p class="prod-tab__category">{{ item.product.category }}</p>
                   <p class="prod-tab__category" id="ID_ml">{{ item.product.ml }} мл.</p>
                   <div class="price">{{ item.product.price }} RUB</div>
                   <div class="quantity__row">
                   <form action="{% url 'remove_cart' %}" method="post" class="removeCartClass">
                       {% csrf_token %}
                       {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                       {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
                       <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ item.product.id }}" id="remove_{{item.product.id}}">
                       <input type="submit" value="-" class="quantity__number-minus"> 
                   </form>
                   <span class="quantity__input" id="quantityID_{{item.product.id}}">{{ item.quantity }}</span>
                   <form action="{% url 'add_certain' %}" method="post" class="addCartClass">
                       {% csrf_token %}
                       {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                       {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
                       <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ item.product.id }}" id="add_{{item.product.id}}">
                       <input type="submit" value="+" class="quantity__number-plus"> 
                   </form>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        print(f"\n\nNew_form: {product_id}\n\n")
        product = Product.objects.get(id=int(product_id))
        cart = Cart(request)
        
        cart.add(product=product)

        item_quantity = cart.get_total_len()

        product_json = serializers.serialize('json', [product])
        product_data = json.loads(product_json)[0]['fields']

        return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'product_instance': product_data, 'quantity': item_quantity})
```

ajax.js

```
$(function() {
    $('.CardForm').on('submit', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var product_id = $(this).find('[name="card_product_id"]').attr('id');
        console.log(product_id, 'another_form');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/add-to-cart/',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                product_id: product_id,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    console.log(response);
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                }
        }
     });     
  });
});
```